# Limit of multiple Quote in a finance google API call

Tags: finance, stocks, stockquotes

I have thousands of stock symbol and  for real time prices requesting finance google API, as an example
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=AAPL
in the above I am getting price of AAPL, so I am considering it like single HTTP request for signle stock i.e AAPL

Now my question is:
- can I pass all the stock symbol (assume 400-500) with comma separte to a single URL,
  If NO then what is  the max limit of symobl that will be going to pass a API URL?
- Another point is , Assume if  I am passing 400-500 stock symbol to a API, will it be consider a single HTTP request?
  or It will be 400/500 HTTP request (as per the passed symbols)

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a simple test, request with multiple comma separated stock symbols can be responded correctly by Google finance:

```
curl -s http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=APPL,FB
```

And I tried to use up to 300 stock symbols and it is working fine for me, and if you pass a really great number of stock symbols in single request (over 3000 stock symbols in my test), [an HTTP 413 response](https://httpstatuses.com/413) is returned by Google's server saying the request is too large to be handled.

About the rate limit, according to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-finance-apis/smjik64hrGY):

> We don't have a formal per day limitation. There is rate limiting per 
>   minute and per hour but it varies depending on the load of the entire 
>   system. If you're refreshing once per minute or two that should be 
>   fine. (and in reality most users aren't modifying their portfolios 
>   every 5 minutes).
>
> There used to be a 200 transaction total, I believe that has been 
>   raised significantly now.