# GetCrumb in Kotlin not getting crumb value

Tags: android, kotlin

**https://mobile-query.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb**

My code is not returning the crumb value from Yahoo Finance API, I tried many different ways but can't fetch it.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Call the function to perform the HTTP GET requests
        performGETRequests()
    }

    private fun performGETRequests() {
        FetchCrumbTask().execute()
    }

    private inner class FetchCrumbTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<String, String>>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Pair<String, String> {
            var cookie: String = ""
            var crumb: String = ""

            try {
                // Step 1: Make the first HTTP GET call to extract the cookie
                val cookieUrl = URL("https://fc.yahoo.com")
                val cookieConnection = cookieUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                cookieConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
                cookieConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Your User-Agent String")
                val cookieResponseCode = cookieConnection.responseCode

                if (cookieResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    val headerFields = cookieConnection.headerFields
                    val cookiesList = headerFields["Set-Cookie"]

                    if (cookiesList != null) {
                        cookie = cookiesList[0] // Assuming there is only one cookie
                    }
                } else {
                    println("First HTTP GET request failed with response code: $cookieResponseCode")
                }

                // Step 2: Make the second HTTP GET call to retrieve the crumb value
                val crumbUrl = URL("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb")
                val crumbConnection = crumbUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                crumbConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
                crumbConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie)
                crumbConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Your User-Agent String")
                val crumbResponseCode = crumbConnection.responseCode

                if (crumbResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(crumbConnection.inputStream))
                    val response = StringBuilder()
                    var line: String?

                    while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                        response.append(line)
                    }
                    reader.close()

                    crumb = response.toString()
                } else {
                    println("Second HTTP GET request failed with response code: $crumbResponseCode")
                }

                // Step 3: Use the obtained cookie and crumb values in subsequent requests
                val targetUrl =
                    "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=TSLA&crumb=$crumb"
                val targetApiUrl = URL(targetUrl)
                val targetConnection = targetApiUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                targetConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
                targetConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie)
                targetConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Your User-Agent String")
                val targetResponseCode = targetConnection.responseCode

                // Process the response and perform further actions as needed

                return Pair(cookie, crumb)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return Pair("", "")
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Pair<String, String>?) {
            // Cache the cookie and crumb values for future use
            val cookie = result?.first
            val crumb = result?.second
            cacheCookieAndCrumb(cookie, crumb)
        }
    }

    private fun cacheCookieAndCrumb(cookie: String?, crumb: String?) {
        // Code to cache the cookie and crumb values for future use
        // Implement your own logic to store these values securely
    }
```

It doesn't return the response I required from this endpoint: https://mobile-query.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb. Please help anyone.